# web part doesnt disply sometimes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I keep getting this error I don't know why as my web part sometimes work just fine and other display this message

Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

Comment: Can you check the ULS log and post any relevant log entries. This info is not sufficient to help your issue

Answer (score 0):

I found some forums relating the same problem.
If you are working in SharePoint 2010:

Was installed in Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 the KB2844286 Security Update.

To fix it you can unistall KB2844286 or you can install an update in

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872441

More information:

http://techchucker.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/issue-kb2844286-security-update-on-sharepoint-2010/

If you are working with SharePoint 2013, take a look at the following article:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31482.sharepoint-web-part-error-unable-to-display-this-web-part.aspx